# Converting LAT LONG coordinates from String to Elapsed Time value

Tags: vb.net, excel, time, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I can retrieve values from our database at work that represent coordinates. I use SQL to retrieve the data and open the results in Excel. They're stored to appear as coordinates in the degrees format, e.g. DDMMSS for LAT and DDDMMSS for LONG.

The excel sheet is created with two columns labeled LAT and LONG. However the values are formatted as General and so Excel treats them as string. e.g. 987654 for LAT and 9876543 for LONG

I need the data as time values to perform Great Circle Distance calculations as described here:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/LatLong.aspx

I manage to convert the string values to Time values by using:

```
=TIME(VALUE(MID(A1,1,2)),VALUE(MID(A1,3,2)),VALUE(MID(A1,5,2)))
```

However the HH values are not maintained.

e.g. 544039 becomes 06:40:39

The 54 becomes an 06 because 54/24 = 2.25 and 0.25*24 = 6

BUT I need to maintain it as 54 not 06.

I believe Excel calls it "Elapsed Time" in the following format:

```
[hh]:mm:ss
```

How can I properly convert 544039 from a string value, to an Elapsed Time value; 54:40:39?

Any help would be appreciated. I'm open to running VB scripts if needed.

Comment: Is it coming in as a string or an integer?

Comment: This doesn't work like you expect because there is no such thing as "time format" for measuring position. There's DMS but those are degrees and go from up to 360 not 60.

Comment: My apologies, I meant DDMMSS, I'll edit the post to correct this.

Comment: @onefineday, by default the cell is formatted as General.

Answer (score 2):

I think your confusion is that with an incoming value of "544039", it can't be HHMMSS, but is actually DegreesMinutesSeconds.  You would be better off converting the MinutesSeconds part of the input string to fractional degrees, and storing the resultant decimal angle, i.e. "544039" becomes 54.6775, which can be stored as a number.  See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion) on how to do the conversion.

Also, Excel stores dates as decimals, so doing this conversion then formatting the results as elapsed time would have the effect you want.  Try entering a time manually, then change its format to decimal and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for the link! You're right about the way Excel handles the values.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great solution to convert it to the necessary number value here:

http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=235046

A reply submitted by Bernard V Liengme, so credit goes to him!

Here's the code:

```
=(INT(A1/10000)/24)+(MOD(INT(A1/100),100)/(24*60))+(MOD(A1,100)/(24*60*60))
```

Thanks to everyone who replied, it helped guide my further searches and taught me a few new things.

Cheers.